# Как добавить пару ключ-значение в словарь, которая уже есть в этом словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно добавить пару ключ-значение в словарь, в котором она уже присутствует.
Т.е есть словарь с одной парой:

```
a = {'one':1}
```

И нужно с помощью кода, добавить вторую такую же пару.

```
a = {'one':1, 'one':1}
```

Этот метод не работает:

```
a['one'] = 1
```

Comment: Никак! По определению у словаря ключи должны иметь уникальные значения. Вам придётся пересмотреть структуру хранения данных...

Comment: @MaxU Точнее, ключи должны быть уникальны. А то непонятно, о каких значениях идёт речь.

Answer (score 5):

У стандартного словаря нет такой возможности. Можно хранить вместо значений списки:

```py
a = { 'one': [1, 2] }

a['one'].append(3)

print(a) # {'one': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Словарь  -  он на то и словарь, что-бы его ключи были уникальными. Правильная конструкция в вашем случае должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
a = {'one':[1,1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не рекомендую, написал по приколу:

```
class NewDict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__keys = []
        self.__values = []

    def add_value(self, key, val):
        self.__keys.append(key)
        self.__values.append(val)

    def get_values(self, key):
        indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(self.__keys) if x == key]
        
        return [self.__values[i] for i in indexes]
```